# Regex skipping to specific phrases

Tags: regex

What is the best way to get regex to 'read' through characters and stop at specific phrases for a capture? A lot of time I have used .*? and .+? to get through unwanted characters to a specific string or tag and then capture.

I want to read through any character until I get to a specific phrase or tag. I would typically do some thing like

```
date.*?<.*?>(\w+)<.*?>
```

from a string that looks like

`datestuffstuffstuffstuff<tag>animal<tag>`

That would work in a simple example but the engine gets lost in 10K character text to match. Do I need to be more specific when I get to the capture? Regex Plain English: *skip characters until you get to this phrase and then capture.*

Comment: The answer is: use regex where it is necessary to parse plain text. Use (X)HTML parser to parse (X)HTML code. Use XML parser to parse XML. Use JSON parser to parse JSON. And so on and so forth.

Comment: Have you considered using a `generator` to feed your text to a match pattern?

Comment: Sorry not specific: this is for matching plain text

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking how to parse plain text, I can suggest using negated character classes, i.e. `[^`+CHARACTERS_THAT_SHOULD_NOT_BE_MATCHED+`]`.

Negated character classes are the most efficient regex subpatterns. Consider

```
word one#word 2#more text
```

The `#(.*?)#` will take 18 steps to find a match, and [`#(\[^#\]*)#`](https://regex101.com/r/mA2kH0/1) will do it in 6 steps.

Also, `.` does not match a newline by default, you need to specify DOTALL mode with `(?s)`, `/s`, or other means in different flavors.

If you need to match some unnecessary text between 2 or more required characters, then you will have to either use `.*`/`.*?` (with or without dotall modifier), or - if you need the closest match - a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) (especially, if some substring must be excluded).